# Couchbase & Spring boot - DefaultOrphanResponseReporter - Orphan responses observed

Tags: spring-boot, timeout, couchbase, orphan

I'm running a `Spring Boot` application that has a `Couchbase` DB.
In the application log, I see hundreds of records like that:

> [cb-orphan-1] [31mWARN [0;39m
>   [32mc.c.c.c.t.DefaultOrphanResponseReporter[0;39m - Orphan responses
>   observed:
>   [{"top":[{"r":"10.250.17.53:8092","s":"view","c":"13963D4B3G6AFE45/FFFFFFFF8F4D718C","l":"10.123.0.197:36530"}],"service":"view","count":1}

They differ from each other in the `c` value and they have different IP & port in the `l`  value.
There is a time difference of few seconds between each of these log records.

After finding [this post](https://forums.couchbase.com/t/defaultorphanresponsereporter-orphan-responses-observed/19011/6) that suggested that somewhere else in the application there should be timeouts, I looked in the logs for such but didn't find any timeout errors.

- How can I know what was the query that resulted in that timeout?
- Is there a way to make this warning more verbose?
- What does the `"c":"13963D4B3G6AFE45/FFFFFFFF8F4D718C"` stands for?

Comment: If the queries are timing out, you should get some RTO log https://blog.couchbase.com/response-time-observability-with-the-java-sdk/

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem. The logs show up even if the client stays completely idle.

- the only way I have found to find out what queries were causing those logs was by debugging the application (breakpoint in the DefaultOrphanResponseReporter class). In my case, they were all KeepAlive requests.
- I don't think the warnings can be made more verbose, maybe by providing custom `OrphanResponseReporter` implementation.
- `c` stands for `last_local_id`. According to the documentation ([tracing-from-the-sdk.html](https://docs.couchbase.com/java-sdk/current/tracing-from-the-sdk.html)), it can be used to correlate logs with server-side logs. Unfortunately, I was not able to do it.